# Including an existing asymptote picture in a LaTeX document

Tags: include, asymptote

I have a project laid out like this: a parent folder, a subfolder named `Main` where the parts for my projects as well as the macros used throughout are, and another `Figures` subfolder containing my Asymptote files. So the figures and documents are in different subfolders.

What I would like to do is include my asymptote code in the same way one includes a TeX document in another.